# How to adjust the height of a series of DIVs by CSS

Tags: css, html, css-float

In a series of DIVs placed in a row with `float:left` ([SEE EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/JM6gw/))

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="box">
        line<br />line<br />line
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        line
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        line<br /><br /><br />line<br />line<br />
    </div>
</div>
```

is it possible to adjust the height of all child `DIV`s to the tallest child `DIV`, which is indeed the actual height of the parent `DIV`. In other words, we want to make the height of all children equal, without knowing the length of content.

I know that the preferred way is to use `JS`, but I am curious if it is possible by `CSS` only. I think it should be possible by considering the parent height, which is defined by the tallest child.

Comment: Not sure it'd be possible with your current markup, but it'd be possible with a table.

Comment: @danrhul I just wish to keep it simple with `float` markup, instead of table or something like that.

Comment: Something like that ? http://jsfiddle.net/JM6gw/4/  if you want change size for height, change .row height

Comment: @artSx "without knowing the length of the content"

Comment: @danrhul So the only way I could suggest is [using `table-cell`](http://jsfiddle.net/JM6gw/7/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put the divs in containers. If you need a div of equal height, the containers will always be the height of the tallest. This does add a bit more complexity to it, but it avoids JS, which I think might be ultimately what you want. If not I can delete this answer.

http://jsfiddle.net/zjScK/1/

HTML

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="container3">
        <div class="container2">
            <div class="container1">
                <div class="box">
                    line<br />line<br />line
                </div>
                <div class="box">
                    line<br /><br /><br />line<br />line<br />line<br /><br /><br />line<br />line<br />
                </div>
                <div class="box">
                    line<br /><br /><br />line<br />line<br />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Stylesheet

```
body
{
    margin:0;
}

.container3 {
    clear:left;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    right:70%;
    background-color:red; /* column 3 background color */
}
.container2 {
    clear:left;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    right:10%;
    background-color:lime; /* column 2 background color */
}
.container1 {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    right:10%;
    background-color:yellow; /* column 1 background color */
}

.box {
    float:left;
    width:10%;
    position:relative;
    left:90%;
    overflow:hidden;
    background-color:blue;
}
```

There is also a reference to this here: http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-5-column.htm

And another post that has a similar question: [Floating divs left, make all divs height equal the tallest div in it's row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4776829/floating-divs-left-make-all-divs-height-equal-the-tallest-div-in-its-row)

Hopefully this helps!