# CSS height 100% in automatic brother div not working in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Can't fixed it...

I have a div with 2 divs inside. The first one determinates height and the second one takes that height. But chrome don't want to do it.

```
<div style="display: table; height: 100%; width: 100%; min-height: 100%;">
    <div FIRST-DIV-HEIGHT-VARIABLE WITH FLOAT LEFT></div>

    <div style="box-sizing: border-box; display: table; float: right; 
    height: auto; min-height: 100%; padding: 0 20px 81px; position: relative; 
    width: 280px; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -ms-box-sizing: border-box; 
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -khtml-box-sizing: border-box; 
    -o-box-sizing: border-box;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: why not include full css code for first div as well? Also you could include a www.jsfiddle.net link to help people help you.

Comment: add display:table-cell for your inner div instead of display:table;

Comment: `FIRST-DIV-HEIGHT-VARIABLE WITH FLOAT LEFT` is not a valid property. you might want to close the div before that. Also, Please avoid using inline styles.. it makes your code unreadable and hard to work with… a separate style sheet can also avoid duplication.. [Why Use CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Why_use_CSS)

Comment: I used inline to make more easily the problem... I use css and all of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flexboxes are the easiest way to create columns of equal height:

```
<style>
  .container {
    display: flex;
    display: -mx-flexbox; // IE10
    display: -webkit-flex; // Safari
    flex-grow: 0;
    -ms-flex-grow: 0; // IE10
    -webkit-flex-grow: 0; // Safari
  }
  .left, .right { width: 50%; }
  .left { 
    background-color: #c66; 
    height: 200px;
  }
  .right { background-color: #66c; }
</style>


<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <p>This is the left DIV.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <p>This is the right DIV.</p>
    <p>Its height is equal to the left DIV.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Flexboxes do not work in IE9 and older. Suresh idea above works in older browsers, but there is a mistake in the code (table cells don't float) and inline CSS is better avoided:

```
<style>
  .container { display: table; }
  .row { display: table-row; }
  .left, .right { 
    display: table-cell;
    width: 50%; 
  }
  .left { 
    background-color: #c66; 
    height: 200px;
  }
  .right { background-color: #66c; }
</style>


<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="left">
      <p>This is the left DIV.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <p>This is the right DIV.</p>
      <p>Its height is equal to the left DIV.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add display:table-cell property for your child div. So that automatically adjust the height of sibling divs.

```
 <div style="display:table; width:100%; height:100%; border:1px solid #f000ff;">
    <div style="height:400px; display:table-cell; background-color:#ff000f;">My Main Content</div>
    <div style="display:table-cell; float:right; height:100%; background-color:#ff00ff;">My Sample Content</div>
</div>
```

Check the [**Working JSFIDDLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/xmv4s/)

In the above fiddle I have assigned the first child div height as 400px. If you modify this height, the right side div automatically adjust its height. Check it out and let me know if any issues.

Comment: just a quick point, if the table is set to height 100% and it takes that height then the inner table-cells will also take that height and ignore the 400px