# Trying to get div heights to be equal based off tallest div

Tags: html, css, wordpress, woocommerce, frontend

So on the front page of the site I'm building - we have a WooCommerce widget that shows products in 3 columns for two rows. - http://goo.gl/GPX1ER

Some of the products have more text than others so the div heights vary - I'd like to have them look uniform by basing the height off the tallest one.

I inspected the element in CSS and found where the width is being derived from (32.3%) - so I added a height element, but its not extending them. I've also worked on the divs above the area also.

I'm at a loss because I know what I can do , I've written it before so not sure what I'm missing

```
`                   <li class="first post-11756 product type-product status-publish has-post-thumbnail product_cat-gift-items shipping-taxable purchasable product-type-simple product-cat-gift-items instock">


    <a href="http://omegawebaz.com/petosa/product/accordion-care-kit/" class="product-images">

        <span class=""><img width="175" height="243" src="http://omegawebaz.com/petosa/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/Cory-Care-Kit.jpg" class="attachment-shop_catalog wp-post-image" alt="Cory Care Kit" /><span class="cart-loading"><i class="fusion-icon-spinner"></i></span></span>
    </a>

    <div class="product-details">

        <div class="product-details-container">

            <h3 class="product-title"><a href="http://omegawebaz.com/petosa/product/accordion-care-kit/">Accordion Care Kit</a></h3>

            <div class="clearfix">



    <span class="price"><span class="amount">&#36;19.95</span></span>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="product-buttons"><div class="product-buttons-container clearfix"><a href="/petosa/?add-to-cart=11756" rel="nofollow" data-product_id="11756" data-product_sku="CCCK" data-quantity="1" class="button add_to_cart_button product_type_simple">Add to cart</a><a href="http://omegawebaz.com/petosa/product/accordion-care-kit/" class="show_details_button">Details</a></div></div>
</li>`



.products-3 > li {
    float: left;
    width: 32.6%;
    margin-right: 1.0%;
    margin-bottom: 11px;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the relevant code (HTML and CSS) here in the question, in the form of a snippet?

Comment: duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4776829/floating-divs-left-make-all-divs-height-equal-the-tallest-div-in-its-row?rq=1

Comment: Check out this plugin: http://brm.io/jquery-match-height/

Comment: Check the link that @Paulie_D sent. Make your outer container display: table-cell; and remove the float and change margin to padding.